# (A \ B) ∪ C = A \ (B \ C) if and only if C ⊂ A. also A,B and C are subsets of X

Tags: elementary-set-theory

\begin{align*}
RHS 
&\Rightarrow A-(B-C) \\
&\Rightarrow A\setminus(B\cap C') \\
&\Rightarrow A \cap (B \cap C')' \\
&\Rightarrow A \cap (B' \cup C) \\
&\Rightarrow (A \cap B') \cup (A \cap C) \\
&\Rightarrow (A\setminus B) \cup C,\\
\end{align*}
since $C ⊂ A$. Hence RHS = LHS

is this the correct approach .

Comment: Please use LaTex.

Comment: To get started with LaTeX, check out [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Dear Lakshya  your proof isnot complete . now let $x\in C$

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate.